# The text overflows, why is it happening?

Tags: hyphenation, columns

I am a double novice. First time at StackExchange and first time using Latex to something real (I practice a lot, but not for relevant things).

It is my CV. I am modifying a downloaded template. I am having an error and I cannot understand why is it happening. In the SKILLS section, the text overflows. Could you help me?

Here an image:
[image: text overflow]

And here the code:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo can be 
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pcr}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering{\Huge Ricardo \textsc{XXXXXX}}\bigskip\par} % Your name

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & MXXXXd  | XXX December XXX \\
\textsc{Address:} & AXXX, Madrid, Spain \\
\textsc{Phone:} & +31 6XXXX94\\
\textsc{email:} & \href{mailto:riXXho@gmail.com}{riXXXXXXXX@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{rl} 
\textsc{July} 2016 & [Scholarship] XXXXXX Build program for \textsc{Entrepreneurship},\\ & \textbf{XXXXXXXX}, Machasusets\\

&\\


%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{} 2008 & [Scholarship] Erasmus Exchange Program\\ & \textbf{École Nationale XXXXXXXXX}, Lyon\\
&\\

\textsc{July} 2016& Local Master in \textsc{}\textsc{XXXXX} \\ & \normalsize\textbf{XXXXXXX}, Madrid\\
&\\


\textsc{July} 2016& Bachelor + Master in \textsc{}\textsc{Architecture} \\ & \normalsize\textbf{XXXXX}, Madrid\\

& - Publication at tomorrow blebleble\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Honors XXXXX}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{June} 2009&  International Baccalaureate (sciences branch) \\ & \textbf{XXX}, Madrid
\end{tabular}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Spanish:} & Mothertongue\\
\textsc{English:} & Fluent\\


\textsc{French:} & Fluent\\
\textsc{Italian:} & Basic Comunication Skills\\
\textsc{Dutch:} & Basic Knowledge\\


\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
Basic: & \textsc{php}, my\textsc{sql},  Python,  {\LaTeX} \\

Intermediate: & \textsc{html}, CSS, Wordpress, Excel, Illustrator, Indesign, Laser Machines, Video Postproduction (Premiere + After Effects) \\

Expert: & \textsc{vba}, Word, PowerPoint, Photoshop, 3D Modeling and Rendering (Rhino + Vray), Parametric Design (Rhino + Grasshopper), Autocad, Autocad Map 3d\\

\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS AND ACTIVITIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests and Activities}

Technology, Open-Source, Programming\\
Paradoxes in Decision Making, Psychoanalysis, Behavioural Finance\\
Football, Travelling

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
    \emph{Current} & Freelance webdesigner, architect and XXXXXXX design expert\textsc{}, XXXXXXXX \\
    \textsc{Mar 2012} 
    & \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \emph{Current} & Architect at \textsc{SXXXXXXX}, Madrid \\
    \textsc{Mar 2012} 
    & \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Computer Graphics Artist at \textsc{XXXXX}, XXXXX, Madrid. \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Architecture Intern at \textsc{XXXXXX}, Barcelona \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Architecture Intern at \textsc{XXXXXX}, Madrid \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jan-Mar 2009} & Architecture Intern at \textsc{XXXXXX}, London \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Extracurricular}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
        %------------------------------------------------


    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jan-Mar 2009} & Volunteer at \textsc{XXXXXArchaeological Project}, XXX, XXX\emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Cells in `l` columns of a `tabular` don't break across lines.

Comment: egreg has said what causes the problem. To fix it either manually break the lines or change the `\begin{tabular}{rl}` specification to a paragraph with something like `\begin{tabular}{rp{0.8\textwidth}}`. Rather than `0.8\textwidth` you can hardwire in the width, say `10cm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tabularx` and the `X` column type to have automatic line breaking. P took the opportunity to improve your table, so that consecutive tables with first columns of almost equal widths do have exactly the same width (with the `\eqmakebox` from `eqparbox`):

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo can be
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections
\usepackage{tabularx, eqparbox}%

 \begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pcr}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering{\Huge Ricardo \textsc{XXXXXX}}\bigskip\par} % Your name

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & MXXXXd | XXX December XXX \\
\textsc{Address:} & AXXX, Madrid, Spain \\
\textsc{Phone:} & +31 6XXXX94\\
\textsc{email:} & \href{mailto:riXXho@gmail.com}{ricardomancho@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\eqmakebox[J][r]{\textsc{July} 2016 }& [Scholarship] XXXXXX Build program for \textsc{Entrepreneurship},\\ & \textbf{XXXXXXXX}, Massachusetts\\

&\\


%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{} 2008 & [Scholarship] Erasmus Exchange Program\\ & \textbf{École Nationale XXXXXXXXX}, Lyon\\
&\\

\textsc{July} 2016& Local Master in \textsc{}\textsc{XXXXX} \\ & \normalsize\textbf{XXXXXXX}, Madrid\\
&\\


\textsc{July} 2016& Bachelor + Master in \textsc{}\textsc{Architecture} \\ & \normalsize\textbf{XXXXX}, Madrid\\

& - Publication at tomorrow blebleble\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Honors XXXXX}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{June} 2009& International Baccalaureate (sciences branch) \\ & \textbf{XXX}, Madrid
\end{tabular}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% LANGUAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\eqmakebox[J][r]{\textsc{Spanish:}} & Mothertongue\\
\textsc{English:} & Fluent\\


\textsc{French:} & Fluent\\
\textsc{Italian:} & Basic Communication Skills\\
\textsc{Dutch:} & Basic Knowledge\\


\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >{\arraybackslash}X@{}}
Basic: & \textsc{php}, my\textsc{sql}, Python, {\LaTeX} \\

Intermediate: & \textsc{html}, CSS, Wordpress, Excel, Illustrator, Indesign, Laser Machines, Video Postproduction (Premiere + After Effects) \\

Expert: & \textsc{vba}, Word, PowerPoint, Photoshop, 3D Modeling and Rendering (Rhino + Vray), Parametric Design (Rhino + Grasshopper), Autocad, Autocad Map 3d\\

\end{tabularx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% INTERESTS AND ACTIVITIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests and Activities}

Technology, Open-Source, Programming\\
Paradoxes in Decision Making, Psychoanalysis, Behavioural Finance\\
Football, Travelling

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r| >{\arraybackslash}X}
    \emph{Current} & Freelance webdesigner, architect and XXXXXXX design expert\textsc{}, XXXXXXXX \\
    \textsc{Mar 2012}
    & \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \emph{Current} & Architect at \textsc{SXXXXXXX}, Madrid \\
    \textsc{Mar 2012}
    & \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Computer Graphics Artist at \textsc{XXXXX}, XXXXX, Madrid. \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Architecture Intern at \textsc{XXXXXX}, Barcelona \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \eqmakebox[L]{\textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011}} & Architecture Intern at \textsc{XXXXXX}, Madrid \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{Jan-Mar 2009} & Architecture Intern at \textsc{XXXXXX}, London \emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabularx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Extracurricular}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r| >{\arraybackslash}X}
        %------------------------------------------------


    %------------------------------------------------

    \eqmakebox[L][r]{\textsc{Jan-Mar 2009}} & Volunteer at \textsc{XXXXXArchaeological Project}, XXX, XXX\emph{}\\
    & \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]